# Business Partner Lies About How much he Charged Customers

Tags: business

The business partner said the customers gave 200 pounds each for the work. £100 for you and £100 for me. Later, it came out that he charged 7,500 pounds for each customer. He lied about the dealings and should he give half of the 7500 pounds each to the partner, who he lied to?

Please answer, JazakAllah

Comment: Salama and welcome to Islam stackexcahnge the question and answer site about Islam. Please consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help] to learn more about this site. If a person lied then Allah is all knowing and will punish them in the hereafter. As for in this life any accusation needs a proof or witnesses so that a faire judge or court can come to a verdict. We cannot just claim something without a proof else we'd be punished for false accusation. Depending on the contract of the business partners shouldn't lie to eachother.

Comment: The proof and witnesses are there.